# Page has field both visible and invisible at the same time

Tags: rspec, capybara

How is it possible the following spec (RSpec 3.8 + Capybara 3.8.2) passes?

```
scenario 'he can dismiss it', js: true do
  find(:dataAttribute, 'tags.addButton').click

  expect(page).to have_field('tag[name]', visible: false)
  expect(page).to have_field('tag[name]')
end
```

Here the HTML

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="tag[name]" id="tag_name" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visible: false` means to not check visibility -- if you want to confirm the element is not visible you need to specify `visible: :hidden`